# WMIC command not working in .bat file

Tags: wmic

I'm new to `WIMC` so probably there will be simple answer to my question.

If I will open `CMD` and run this command:

`wmic /OUTPUT:C:\LogServices.txt service where "not PathName like '%Windows%'" get DisplayName,Name,PathName,State,StartMode`

this will generate file with all services not in windows folder.

If I will save above command in bat file and run this will generate list all services somehow ignoring `WHERE` statement. Running this as Administrator not changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a batch script you have to double pump the `%` signs so they'll be treated as literal percent signs.  Change your command to this and it'll work:

`wmic /OUTPUT:C:\LogServices.txt service where "not PathName like '%%Windows%%'" get DisplayName,Name,PathName,State,StartMode`